# RESTful - Usage of same Resource Entity in POST & PATCH API?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a web project which exposes REST API's to the client, consisting many crud API's like POST /identity, GET /identity but now we wanted to expose another API i.e. PATCH /identity. 
Talking about POST /identity which takes request body of type json, below quoted example:

```
{
    "name": "name1",
    "parameters": {
        "key1": 1,
        "key2": 3600,
        "key3": true
    }
}
```

On the controller side, we're casting above JSON body into POJO, let's call this Identity.java and name field is marked as required in @JSONProperty annotation but when we want to introduce PATCH API over this workflow, we expect below json will be passed as the request body.

```
{
        "parameters": {
            "key1": 2,
            "key2": 7200,
            "key3": false
        }
}
```

Is there a way in jersey, I can still use same Identity POJO to cast above request body? Because with name field enabled with required validation, it's not allowing us to use Identity POJO?

Comment: The design intent is that a `PATCH` payload is a set of modification instructions, not an updated representation. From the PATCH RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789#section-2) : With PATCH, however, the enclosed entity contains a set of instructions describing how a resource currently residing on the origin server should be modified to produce a new version.

Comment: Thanks @EricStein, link was quite helpful!